# CopyOnWriteArraySet is too slow

Tags: java

When I ran the following program, it took around 7 to 8 minutes to execute. I am really not sure where I am mistaken as this program is taking so much time to execute.

```
public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Integer[] a= new Integer[1000000];
            for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i] = i;
            }
            final List<Integer> source = Arrays.asList(a);
            final Set<Integer> set = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<Integer>(source);
        }
    }
```

Can some one help me understand, why this program is too slow.

My machine is Core I7  with 4GB RAM

Comment: As the documentation says, a CopyOnWriteArraysSet is backed by a CopyOnWriteArraysList, and is *best suited for applications in which set sizes generally stay small*. 1,000,000 is far from being small. The operation is O(n^2).

Comment: @Siguza that is really not the problem. It doesn't take much time at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tested and indeed with a List of 1 000 000 elements provided to the constructor, it takes a good time (7 minutes).

It is a referenced issue on Open JDK the 2013-01-09 :
[JDK-8005953 - CopyOnWriteArraySet copy constructor is unusable for large collections](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8005953)

The problem would cause by the `CopyOnWriteArrayList#addAllAbsent()` method invoked by the `CopyOnWriteArraySet` constructor.

Extract of the issue :

> CopyOnWriteArraySet's copy constructor is too slow for large
>   collections. It takes over 10 minutes on a developer laptop with just
>   1 million entries in the collection to be copied...

As resolution status, you can read : **Won't Fix**.
And you can read as last message :

> addAllAbsent can be made faster for larger input, but it would impact
>   the performance for small sizes.  And it's documented that
>   CopyOnWriteXXX classes are better suited for collections of small
>   sizes.

The [`CopyOnWriteArraySet` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) specifies indeed this point :

> It is best suited for applications in which set sizes generally stay
>   small, read-only operations vastly outnumber mutative operations, and
>   you need to prevent interference among threads during traversal.

Comment: Glancing at `addAllAbsent()`, it looks like the cost is in converting the input collection, which might contain duplicates, into a set of unique items. Does not seem to be any special case for constructing from an existing set.